# Composition of functions f, g and h

Tags: functions, function-and-relation-composition

Consider the function $f:\mathbb{N}\to\mathbb{N}$ given by $f(x)=2x$.

1) Find the function $g:\mathbb{N}\to\mathbb{N}$ with the property that $$g(f(x))=x$$ for all $x$ from $\mathbb{N}$.

2) Prove that there is no function $h:\mathbb{N}\to\mathbb{N}$ with the property that $$f(h(x))=x$$ for all natural $x$.

Comment: Your question was put on hold, the message above (and possibly comments) should give an explanation why. (In particular, [this link](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/a/9960) might be useful.) You might try to edit your question to address these issues. Note that the next edit puts your post in the review queue, where users can vote whether to reopen it or leave it closed. (Therefore it would be good to avoid minor edits and improve your question as much as possible with the next edit.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Part $(1)$: You can choose
$$g(x)=\begin{cases}\frac{x}{2}\quad\text{$x$ is even}\\0\quad\text{otherwise}\end{cases}$$
Note that $g$ maps numbers to $\mathbb{N}$.

Part $(2)$:
Since the domain of $f$ is $\mathbb{N}$ and $f(x)$ is even for all $x\in\mathbb{N}$, you can't have 
$$f(h(x))=x$$
for odd $x$.

Comment: * 1 otherwise (since the smallest natural number is 1)

Comment: @Lydia The definition of natural numbers is a bit ambiguous; some like to include 0 in the naturals and others don't :). See: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Natural_number

Answer (score 0):

Here is a hint: For part (1), notice that $f$ maps $x$ to $2x$. You are being asked to find a function $g$ that undoes the map as the output of $g$ is $x$. I hope that helps find out the answer to part (a).